# What's the C strategy to "imitate" a C++ template ?

Tags: c++, c, templates, macros, c-preprocessor

After reading some examples on stackoverflow, and following some of the answers for my previous questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001434/c-macro-issue-redefinition-of-functions-structure)), I've eventually come with a "strategy" for this.

I've come to this:

**1)** Have a declare section in the `.h` file. Here I will define the data-structure, and the accesing interface. Eg.:

```
/**
 * LIST DECLARATION. (DOUBLE LINKED LIST)
 */
#define NM_TEMPLATE_DECLARE_LIST(type) \
typedef struct nm_list_elem_##type##_s { \
    type data; \
    struct nm_list_elem_##type##_s *next; \
    struct nm_list_elem_##type##_s *prev; \
} nm_list_elem_##type ; \
typedef struct nm_list_##type##_s { \
    unsigned int size; \
    nm_list_elem_##type *head; \
    nm_list_elem_##type *tail; \
    int (*cmp)(const type e1, const type e2); \
} nm_list_##type ; \
\
nm_list_##type *nm_list_new_##type##_(int (*cmp)(const type e1, \
    const type e2)); \
\
(...other functions ...)
```

**2)** Wrap the functions in the interface inside MACROS:

```
/**
 * LIST INTERFACE
 */
#define nm_list(type) \
    nm_list_##type

#define nm_list_elem(type) \
    nm_list_elem_##type

#define nm_list_new(type,cmp) \
    nm_list_new_##type##_(cmp)

#define nm_list_delete(type, list, dst) \
    nm_list_delete_##type##_(list, dst)

#define nm_list_ins_next(type,list, elem, data) \
    nm_list_ins_next_##type##_(list, elem, data)

(...others...)
```

**3)** Implement the functions:

```
/**
 * LIST FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
 */
#define NM_TEMPLATE_DEFINE_LIST(type) \
nm_list_##type *nm_list_new_##type##_(int (*cmp)(const type e1, \
    const type e2)) \
{\
    nm_list_##type *list = NULL; \
    list = nm_alloc(sizeof(*list)); \
    list->size = 0; \
    list->head = NULL; \
    list->tail = NULL; \
    list->cmp = cmp; \
}\
void nm_list_delete_##type##_(nm_list_##type *list, \
    void (*destructor)(nm_list_elem_##type elem)) \
{ \
    type data; \
    while(nm_list_size(list)){ \
        data = nm_list_rem_##type(list, tail); \
        if(destructor){ \
            destructor(data); \
        } \
    } \
    nm_free(list); \
} \
(...others...)
```

In order to use those constructs, I have to create two files (let's call them `templates.c` and `templates.h`) .

In `templates.h` I will have to `NM_TEMPLATE_DECLARE_LIST(int)`, `NM_TEMPLATE_DECLARE_LIST(double)` , while in `templates.c` I will need to `NM_TEMPLATE_DEFINE_LIST(int)` , `NM_TEMPLATE_DEFINE_LIST(double)` , in order to have the code behind a list of ints, doubles and so on, generated.

By following this strategy I will have to keep all my "template" declarations in two files, and in the same time, I will need to include `templates.h` whenever I need the data structures. It's a very "centralized" solution.

Do you know other strategy in order to "imitate" (at some point) templates in C++ ? Do you know a way to improve this strategy, in order to keep things in more decentralized manner, so that I won't need the two files: `templates.c` and `templates.h` ?

Comment: You could implement a language which supports templates on top of C. ;)

While I don't know an alternative method off the top of my head that I'd consider suitable, this is the way almost everyone accomplishes this pattern when they do need templates, from my experience.

Comment: I suppose using C++ would be out of the question?

Comment: Yes, C++ is out of the question.

Comment: @jer: Why invent yourself? Just use [Comeau C++](http://www.comeaucomputing.com). The most standard-conforming C++ compiler comes with excellent error messages and generates C code.

Comment: @sbi, That part of the comment was mostly facetious, ergo the smiley.

Comment: @jer: Didn't you see where my tongue was?

Comment: Honestly, I think it might be simpler to just build some code generator to will generate the data structures for you. You could prefix functions with the type-name (or whatever naming convention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is only one of the many possible uses of templates - generating a generic data structure. This example doesn't need any of the inference which makes templates powerful; asking for something which lets you create generic data structures is not really the same question as asking for something equivalent to C++ templates.

Some of the implementation techniques used for `<tgmath.h>` might give some type inference capabilities, but they is still much weaker and less portable than C++ templates.

For the specific example of containers, I wouldn't bother - just create a list with void* data in it, and  either use malloc and free to create the data, or give the list have a pair of function pointers to create and destroy values. You can also just rely on the client to manage the data, rather than having the value as a member of the list. If you want to save the indirection, use a variable length array as the data member. As C isn't as type-safe as C++, having void* data isn't an issue.

You can do some sophisticated code generation with macros, but there are also other tools to generate code. Personally I like using XSLT for code generation, but then you have a completely non-C-like part of your build process.

Answer (score 2):

I probably shouldn't admit to doing this, but when I needed "templatized" containers in C land in the past, I wrote the 'templatized queue class' as a pair of special files, like this:

File MyQueue.include_h:

```
/** NOTE: THIS IS NOT a REAL .h FILE, it only looks like one!  Don't #include it! */
struct MyQueueClass
{
   void init_queue(MyQueueClass * q);
   void push_back(MyQueueClass * q, MyQueueClassItem * item);

   [....All the other standard queue header declarations would go here....]

   MyQueueClassItem * _head;
   MyQueueClassItem * _tail;
   int _size;
};
```

File MyQueue.include_c:

```
/** NOTE: THIS IS NOT A REAL .c FILE, it only looks like one! Don't compile directly! */
void init_queue(MyQueueClass * q)
{
   q->_size = 0;
   q->_head = q->_tail = NULL;
}

void push_back(MyQueueClass * q, MyQueueClassItem * item)
{
   if (q->_head == NULL) q->_head = q->_tail = item;
   else
   {
      q->_tail->_next = item;
      item->_prev = q->_tail;
      q->_tail = item;
   }
   q->_size++;
}

[....All the other standard queue function bodies would go here....]
```

Then, whenever I wanted to "instantiate" my Queue "template" to use a particular item-type, I'd put something like this into an actual .c and .h file:

In one of my real .h files:

```
#define MyQueueClass struct SomeSpecificQueueType
#define MyQueueClassItem struct SomeSpecificQueueTypeItem
# include "MyQueue.include_h"
#undef MyQueueClassItem
#undef MyQueueClass
```

In one of my real .c files (it doesn't matter which one):

```
#define MyQueueClass struct SomeSpecificQueueType
#define MyQueueClassItem struct SomeSpecificQueueTypeItem
# include "MyQueue.include_c"
#undef MyQueueClass
#undef MyQueueClassItem
```

.... and presto, the C preprocessor acts as a poor man's template-expander, without requiring the entire "template definition" to be made out of a giant #define statement.

Comment: It wouldn't allow declaring two queues holding values of different types in one file - function names will clash.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself some trouble and use existing [`queue(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/queue/) set of macros - tried and tested, used in kernel sources, etc.